# node express error middleware wont work calling from browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i want to return a 401 error from my API

this code works when calling the API from postman or from another server,
problem is when calling from the browser, I am getting a CORS error (cors are fine when request don't return an error)

```
router.options('*', cors());

    router.use(function (err, req, res, next) {

            if (err.status === 401) {
                res.status(err.status).send({ message: err.message });
            }
        });

        router.use(fileUpload({
            createParentPath: true,
            limits: {
                fileSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 //2MB max file(s) size
            },
        }));


        router.get('/account', cors(), async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {

  })
```

the cors error [image]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You would have to show us exactly what the incoming request is that has trouble (headers and everything).  Postman does not enforce CORs - only browsers do so that's why it works fine from Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this middleware at first

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE");

  next();
});
```